# Debian 9 (Stretch): Firefox Quantum is now in Stable, where can I get my Add-ons back?

Tags: debian, firefox, browser, plugin

Recently Firefox Quantum has moved into Debian Stable (= Stretch).

When updating my system via `apt-get upgrade` the old Firefox-ESR has been replaced with the new one. Now all my previously working Add-ons have gone.

---

Is there any option to get my Add-ons back (in best case from the official Stable repositories)?

- NoScript
- HTTPSEverywhere
- UBlockOrigin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox 60 no longer supports XUL extensions, so the extensions provided by `xul-ext-` packages no longer work with it. You’ll need to wait for the equivalent `webext-` packages to be made available in Debian 9. There are bugs asking for this already, you can subscribe to them to get updates:

- [HTTPS Everywhere](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=906874) (this has been uploaded and is [available in Debian 9](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/webext-https-everywhere))
- [NoScript](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=882287) (this has been uploaded for Debian 10, but not yet for Debian 9)
- [UBlock Origin](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=908311) (this has been uploaded and is [available in Debian 9](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/webext-ublock-origin))

Alternatively, you can [install them manually](https://addons.mozilla.org/) in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

- UBlock Origin
- HTTPS Everywhere

are available from the official https://addons.mozilla.org .  Tested on an up to date Debian 9 (Stretch).

A rewrite of NoScript for WebExtensions is also available from the same source.

The WebExtensions version of NoScript did not work as well for me.  I now use uMatrix, from the same author as UBlock Origin, which I have come to prefer.  I have one pointer when using this: when enabling/disabling first-party scripts, you may need to force-refresh (e.g. ctrl+F5) in order to apply the change.